# React Navigation takes long to navigate to page with image (local or remote) | React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am building a React Native app and use React Navigation. If I call `navigation.navigate()` to a page that has images, either remote or locally, it takes about a second before actually navigating.

This happens even if I go to that page multiple times, seemingly the images are not cached.

I would think that at least the local images should be fast. Am I supposed to be pre-fetching them or something?

Comment: How large is your image? It should be appropriate size (not too bigger than where it's used) to load reasonably fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just in Expo development and when I deployed to TestFlight, the speeds improved dramatically.